# Where are the redistributable merge modules for Visual Studio C++ Express edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, wix, wix3

I have created MSI installers for programs compiled with Visual C++ 2008 Express edition and Wix (Windows Installer Xml) before.  I just needed to bring in the merge modules for the C++ runtime redistributables from c:\Program Files\Common Files\Merge Modules*.msm.  I expected the procedure would be similar with Visual C++ 2010 Express, but so far I have not been able to find the merge modules. Are they perhaps no longer in the Express edition? Is there a new preferred way to create a windows installer with Wix for my C++ application that includes the runtime redistributables?

Thanks in advance for any help or advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The merge modules are not included with Visual C++ Express 2010.  Sadness and despair.

Answer (score 1):

You can search GitHub for a project already containing the desired merge modules. For example: [Microsoft_VC100_CRT_x64.msm](https://www.google.de/search?q=github%20Microsoft_VC100_CRT_x64.msm&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=ZeKgVvXwPMWHPpXegeAL)